# how to pass variable in url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am integrating instamojo payment gateway in website.i am using codeigniter framework.

I passed redirect URL as

```
http://localhost/example/instapayment/redirect
```

So i get response as follow:

```
http://localhost/example/instapayment/redirect?payment_id=MOJO612323222&status=success
```

i am redirecting to base_url. My route is

```
$route['redirect/(:any)'] = 'instapayment/redirect/$1';
```

Now i am not getting how to access status and payment_id.

Comment: The CI way: $this->input->get('payment_id')

Answer (score 1):

if you have to pass the value you should enter url like this

```
localhost/yoururl/index.php/products_controller/delete_controller/70
```

and in controller function you can read like this

```
function delete_controller( $product_id = NULL ) {
 echo $product_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost/example/instapayment/redirect?payment_id=MOJO612323222&status=success

if passing the variable in url that is bad practice , still if u want this u can use

`$this->input->post()` //for post menthod

`$this->input->get()`// for get method

Comment: i am not passing variable in url.my payment gateway giving me response like this.$this->input->get() not working

Comment: for payment_id u must use $this->input->get('payment_id') same for status